# Глагол "строчить" (быстро писать) какого управления требует?

Tags: управление

У меня:

> ...и две юные француженки, которые, так же как и я, яростно строчили в
>   свои блокнотики.

Я взялась было править на "в своих блокнотиках", да засумлевалася...

Comment: Жёвтонькое надо оставить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы остановился на "двойном" управлении, добавив прямое дополнение:

> ... строчили *что-то* в своих блокнотиках.

На строгую переходность глагола указывает его замена смысловым аналогом: *записывать (**что-либо**) в строку (строками), располагая строки **где-то***.

Comment: Александр, а почему Вы после многоточия в начале фразы ставите пробел? Вот же правила: https://orfogrammka.ru/типографика/пробел_и_знаки_пунктуации и http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F&start=30 (вопрос 235848).

Comment: Я смотрю на это как на _окончание_ реального предложения.

Comment: Странно, а я как на продолжение того, что не показано.

Comment: Тёмыч, ты прав!